# Search in JQGrid using external textbox

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid

I am using JQGrid for displaying records. I have a text box and a button somewhere on the page for search purpose. I want to search and filter the rows that contains the search word. I hardly find a solution for this over net. Currently on button click, I am making a DB search and reloading the grid. But, I want to do it on the client side due to performance implications.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is for adding button in the table header and button click event

```
 $('#t_list')
               .append($("<div><label for=\"globalSearchText\">Global Search:&nbsp;</label><input id=\"globalSearchText\" class=\"jqsearch\" type=\"text\"></input>&nbsp;<button id=\"globalSearch\" type=\"button\">Search</button></div>"));
        $("#globalSearchText").keypress(function (e) {
            var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
            if (key === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) { // 13
                $("#globalSearch").click();
            }
        });
```

And below is for search locally

```
$("#globalSearch").button({
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-search" },
            text: false
        }).click(function () {
            var postData = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData"),
                colModel = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
                rules = [],
                searchText = $("#globalSearchText").val(),
                l = colModel.length,
                i,
                cm;
            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                cm = colModel[i];
                if (cm.search !== false && (cm.stype === undefined || cm.stype === "text")) {
                    rules.push({
                        field: cm.name,
                        op: "cn",
                        data: searchText
                    });
                }
            }
            postData.filters = JSON.stringify({
                groupOp: "OR",
                rules: rules
            });
            $grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", { search: true });
            $grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1, current: true }]);
            return false;
        });
```